# Google custom search json api refinement labels

Tags: google-api

I am building out a site search using the google custom json/rest api, but I am not sure how to get the 'facet/ refinement labels' to filter down the results.

They are being returned in the json, but I haven't seen anything in the documentation that explains how to filter with it.

Answer (score 3):

To filter with facet, value of q parameter should be like this:

```
text_to_search more:facet_name
```

Answer (score 2):

After you have [added refinement labels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFyuqPzW1zA) to your custom search, you have to add the **facet name** into your search query to "activate" the filter. Your **facet name** will be named the same as you named your **refinement label**. If you named your **refinement label** "*race bicycles*", you need to add `more:race_bicycles` to your query. You can also find your **facet name** in the [response meta data](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list) of your request in `label_with_op`. Just copy and past your `label_with_op` in your query.

For using the api in python, the request looks something like this:

```
params = {
    "q" : "bicycles more:race_bicycles",
    "cx": cx,
    "key": key,
    }

page = requests.request("GET", url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1" , params=params)

results = json.loads(page.text)
```